# DJango How to build a formset for a Quiz?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm working on a quiz application that needs to display a quiz to be taken
My models .py looks like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin

#######################
#Quiz Structure Models#
#######################

class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    creation = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.name

    def possible(self):
        total = 0
        for question in self.question_set.all():
            question.save()
            total += question.value
        return total



class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    creation = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    #objective = TODO: include standards linking in later versions
    value = models.IntegerField(default = 1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    #Creator is tied to the quiz


##########
#Attempts#
##########
class QuizAttempt(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    #Score Method (similar to possible in Quiz 


class QuestionAttempt(models.Model):
    attempt = models.ForeignKey(QuizAttempt)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    response = models.ForeignKey(Answer)


#######
#Admin#
#######

class QuestionInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Question
    extra = 2


class AnswerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Answer
    extra = 2


class QuizAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'creator', 'creation', 'possible',)
    search_fields = ('name', 'creator')
    inlines = [QuestionInline]

admin.site.register(Quiz, QuizAdmin)

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnswerInline]
    search_fields = ('question', 'quiz', 'value',)
    list_display = ('question', 'quiz', 'value',)

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

I'm trying to build a form or form-set that will let me have a form for a quiz attempt that contains all of the questions so it looks something like this, and will let me get that back in a view to save a student's attempt at a quiz.

1. Question 1

   - Option a
   - ect

So far it looks like my best solution is to build a formset out of these models, but I'm not sure how to specify my choices to limit it to answers associated with the current question, or how to get the right formset in a view.

Comment: As a thought, would it be better to put each question on a page, and just pass the quiz_attempt along?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you'll probably want to create a custom `Form` at execute time, and many custom `Field`s.  I would expect something along the lines of:

```
class QuizForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, data, questions, *args, **kwargs):
        self.questions = questions
        for question in questions:
            field_name = "question_%d" % question.pk
            choices = []
            for answer in question.answer_set().all():
                choices.append((answer.pk, answer.answer,))
            ## May need to pass some initial data, etc:
            field = forms.ChoiceField(label=question.question, required=True, 
                                      choices=choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
        return super(QuizForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
    def save(self):
        ## Loop back through the question/answer fields and manually
        ## update the Attempt instance before returning it.
```

It will likely take additional tweaking to make this work through the admin interface, but this should give you a good start for constructing the form itself at execution time.

Your view would probably look something like:

```
# Assuming something like:  /quiz/69/ with "69" being the quiz PK.
def render_quiz(request, quiz_id):
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, quiz_id)
    form = QuizForm(questions=quiz.question_set.all())
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuizForm(request.POST, questions=quiz.question_set.all())
        if form.is_valid(): ## Will only ensure the option exists, not correctness.
            attempt = form.save()
            return redirect(attempt)
    return render_to_response('quiz.html', {"form": form})
```

Comment: How can I be sure I'd get the same form back when I receive the post data?

Comment: Forgot to include the view code.  Updated.  There is a race condition that exists if the Questions are updated between the time the Form is rendered and the time the answers are submitted.  This should, however, show up as a question that was not answered (or that the answer doesn't exist, etc), and take the user back to the new form.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation!

Comment: is it still the idiomatic way to achieve this? What does 'data' argument refer to here

Answer (score 2):

This is a rough idea of how it should work.

```
# define a form
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput) # make it hidden- i know, not very elegant
    question = forms.CharField()
    answer = forms.CharField()

# views.py
def display(request):
    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(creator=request.user) # or some definition of quiz
    questions = quiz.question_set.all().values('id','question') # to get question text

    # define a formset
    QuestionFormSet = formset_factory(QuestionForm)
    # add initial data
    formset = QuestionFormSet(initial=questions)
    # should work because the field names are the same as that of form

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = QuestionFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            # associate answers here, note that you have access to the question id,
            # which is a hidden field in your form
```

Comment: This is great for adding questions, I'll probably be using this for that. It doesn't quite do what I want. What I'm trying for is auto generate a quiz attempt. The goal here is to make a bunch of new Question attempts associated with a Quiz attempt for the current